# Android Studio: Can't Resolve Symbols

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have searched and searched for a solution to my problem. I have found many possible solutions, but none have worked. I've "Invalidate Caches / Restart", rebuilding, cleaning, resyncing. The project worked before I committed to GitHub for a project submission. I booted my computer back up (admitedly possibly after some updates to Windows 10), opened the project (no changes made from the commit), and all of the sudden several android imports do not work anymore – Android Studio claims it "cannot resolve symbol".

[HERE](https://github.com/seanfrisbey/Udacity-Popular-Movies-App-Stage-1) is my source repository. The project worked for the instructor, and it worked before submission. I don't know what changed. Any ideas?

GRADLE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.persistentdevelopment.watchit"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY (** denotes "cannot resolve symbol")

```
package com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.activities;

** import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
** import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
** import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.R;
import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.adapters.MovieAdapter;
import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.objects.Movie;
import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.interfaces.AsyncResponse;
import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.utilities.TmdbUtils;
import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.utilities.TmdbUtils.QueryMode;
import com.persistentdevelopment.watchit.utilities.NetworkUtils;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please replace the link to an image of your code with your actual code as text. Having the text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test your problem and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem with mine. While I did reinstall Android Studio, I did not clear the app cache. I uninstalled it again, deleted the `%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio3.2` folder, and reinstalled Android Studio